# Invalid initialization error while upcasting and downcasting an object

Tags: c++, class, downcast

Consider the following code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include<iostream>

class Parent
{
public:
   virtual void foo() const{};
};

class Child_A: public virtual Parent
{
};

void downcast( const Child_A& aa)
{
}

void upcast( const Parent& pp )
{
  std::cout<< typeid( pp ).name() << std::endl;
  downcast(pp); // line 21: This is the problematic line!
}


int main()
{
  Child_A aa;
  upcast(aa);
  return 0;
}
```

I get a compiling error:

*initialization.cpp:21:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Child_A&' from expression of type 'const Parent'*

*downcast(pp);*

But if I compile the code without line 27, `typeid( pp ).name()` returns `7Child_A`.

So why do I get this error? How can I fix it? and What is really the type of `pp`?

Comment: `typeid` is a runtime operator. Given just `upcast`, the compiler has no clue that `pp` is actually a `Child_A`.

Comment: `pp` is a reference to `Parent`. You can't pass a reference to `Parent` to a function that expects a reference to `Child_A`. (And there's no casting in this code, only implicit conversion.)

Comment: This question is overly complicated and could be pared down to a much smaller, representative example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an implicit derived-to-base conversion on the `upcast(aa)` line. `pp` refers to the base class subobject contained in `aa`. There is no implicit base-to-derived conversion. `static_cast` can be used to perform a downcast, but since `Parent` is a virtual base you'll have to use `dynamic_cast` instead:

```
if (Child_A* c = dynamic_cast<Child_A const*>(&pp)) {
    downcast(*c);
}
```

The line `typeid(pp).name()` returns a child class output string because when applied to an object of polymorphic type (`Parent` has a virtual method so it is polymorphic), the result is the most derived class:

> When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers.

Note that `pp`'s actual static type is `Parent const&`. [`typeid` isn't a very reliable way to get the type of an object.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/extended_type_info.html)

Comment: `static_cast` does not work here. `Parent` is a virtual base of `Child_A`.

Comment: @Lingxi Right. So he will have to use `dynamic_cast`

Comment: Back from the future. The type of `c` should be `Child_A const*`. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Downcast cannot be done implicitly. To correct it, you can make the cast explicit through either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`. However, since `Parent` is a virtual base of `Child_A`. Only `dynamic_cast` applies here. So, to make your code correct, you could change `downcast(pp);` to `downcast(dynamic_cast<const Child_A&>(pp));`. Within `void upcast( const Parent& pp )`, the static type of `pp` is `Parent` but its dynamic type (real type) is `Child_A`. `typeid` queries dynamic type, and that is why `7Child_A` gets printed.